# Atribuir função dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html

### Exemplo:

```
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="close"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="close"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="close"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Digamos que em meu código, eu tenha vários elementos com a classe `.box` e eu queria atribuir ao elemento `.close`, uma função que remova da página o .box que a possui, sem ter que atribuir inline no html, ou a cada uma individualmente no javascript. Como fazer?

Comment: @Erik ou seja, vc quer que quando clicar no close, feche a caixa que esta esse close?

Comment: Isso. Gostaria de remove-la.

Comment: Está usando jQuery ou não ?

Comment: Não. Gostaria da solução em Javascript puro.

Comment: Estou montando um exemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se esse atende sua necessidade;

```js
var closestByClass = function(el, clazz) {
  while (el.className != clazz) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (!el) {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return el;
}

document.onclick = function(e) {
  var el = closestByClass(e.target, 'box')
  el.style.display = 'none';
};
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
    Teste
    <div class="close">x</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    Teste
    <div class="close">x</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    Teste
    <div class="close">x</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Isso! Valeu, Zoom!
PS.: Cuidado com o flash.

Comment: Fui cegado pelo flash.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro selecione os elementos cuja classe seja close depois acione o evento de click nele, quando o usuário clicar irá remover o parentNode "acima", lembre-se, a relação de elementos funcionam como uma arvore.

```js
var close = document.querySelectorAll('.close');

for (var i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    this.parentNode.remove();
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="close">Close</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="close">Close</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="close">Close</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode adicionar um evento para capturar todos os eventos de `click` no `body`, ou restringir a um *container* onde estarão todos os `.box`:

```
document.querySelector(".container_boxs").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  //...
});
```

E verificar nesse evento se o elemento clicado está na hierarquia DOM esperada:

```
if (e.target.className.toLowerCase() == 'close' && e.target.parentElement.className.toLowerCase() == 'box') {
  alert('Você clicou no elemento close');
}
```

E por fim remove o elemento *parent* do item clicado, no caso o `.box`:

```
// remove o parent do item clicado.
e.target.parentElement.remove();
```

Exemplo completo:

```js
document.querySelector(".container_boxs").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.className.toLowerCase() == 'close' && e.target.parentElement.className.toLowerCase() == 'box') {
    // remove o parent do item clicado.
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box .close:after {
  content: "\00d7";
}
.box .close {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_boxs">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="close"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Exemplo completo jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/3gw34w37/3/)

> Créditos a base da solução: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9649651/2290538

Comment: Boa solução também, Fernando, Obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Use `jQuery` para fazer integrações na interface

Espero que seja o que está procurando.

abaixo o código:

```
<body>
<div class="box1">
    <h2>
      Div1
    </h2>
    <button onclick="deletaDiv(1)">Apagar1</button>
</div>

<div class="box2">
    <h2>
      Div2
    </h2>
    <button onclick="deletaDiv(2)">Apagar2</button>
</div>

<div class="box3">
    <h2>
      Div3
    </h2>
    <button onclick="deletaDiv(3)">Apagar3</button>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    function deletaDiv(id){
        $(".box"+id).hide();
    }
</script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9au451t8/)

Comment: Como eu disse, não quero usar o JS inline no html.
tambem não quero usar jQuery. Gostaria da solução em js puro.